# Need help defining function using Sum

Tags: summation, core-language

Can anyone help me to calculate:

```
hdnm[n_, m_] = 
  Sum[
    hd[n1_, n2_, n_, m_] 
      (Subscript[a, j, n2] Subscript[b, j, n1] + 
       Subscript[b, j, n2] Subscript[a, j, n1]),
    {j, 1, 3}, {n1, 1, 3}, {n2, 1, 3}]
```

in which `hd[n1_, n2_, n_, m_]` is a function which I have defined in my program before. now I want to multiply this function by `(Subscript[a, j, n2] Subscript[b, j, n1] + Subscript[b, j, n2] Subscript[a, j, n1])` and do the summation over `j`, `n1` & `n2`.

I do not have the values for `Subscript[a, j, n2], Subscript[b, j, n1], Subscript[b, j, n2]` and `Subscript[a, j, n1]`. so I want to guess the values. For instance. `Subscript [a, j, n2] = 1` if `j == n2` and `Subscript[a, j, n2] = 0` if `j` is not equal to `n2`.

Later in my program I need to substitute these variables with the new values I'm calculating using an iteration method.

Answer (score 1):

can you do something like this:

```
hdnm[n_, m_] := Sum[ hd[n1_, n2_, n, m] Which[j == n2,
(Subscript[b, j, n1] + Subscript[b, j, n2] Subscript[a, j, n1]),
j != n2, (Subscript[b, j, n2] Subscript[a, j, n1])],
{j, 1, 3}, {n1, 1, 3}, {n2, 1, 3}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I rewrote the hdnm such that it includes the coefficients from the begining and my problem solved.